# How to Hide selected Media files from all applications in Android?

Tags: android, gallery, show-hide

I want to make an application that will give user an option to select the files form gallery then will hide those selected files form all other applications running on the Android phone...
Any suggestions how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put them in a folder and include a file called .nomedia.

However, if the folder is shared, e.g. on the SDCard, then the user can browse to them with a file explorer.

To stop this, you can change the permissions on the files but this doesn't work in the device is rooted.